# Html Bugs in Opera

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

In versions of opera greater than 9.0, I have found a bug that fails to render a large portion of my text. This happens with links, span and strong tags. As well as this, it throws a strange error with sup tags.

Here is the link to the live site: http://clients.bionic-comms.co.uk/licensingawards/microsite/enter.html
Below is the code (the first div doesn't give me any problems at all):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Licensing Awards '09 - Enter Your Products</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <!--[if IE 6]> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/noscript.css"></noscript>
    <script src="js/shadedborder/shadedborder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="otherbits">
        <a href="about.html" id="licensing" name="About"><i>About</i></a>
        <a href="http://www.bionic-comms.co.uk" id="bionic" name="Bionic"><i>Bionic</i></a>
      </div>
      <div id="header">
        <div id="nav">
          <div id="menu"> 
            <a href="enter.html" id="home" name="Home"><i>Home</i></a>
            <a href="nominate.html" id="nominate" name="nominate"><i>nominate</i></a>
            <a href="tickets.html" id="tickets" name="tickets"><i>tickets</i></a>
            <a href="about.html" id="about" name="about"><i>about</i></a>
            <a href="photos.html" id="photos" name="photos"><i>photos</i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="lildetails">
        <p>Thursday September 10th 2009, Royal Lancaster Hotel, London &bull; Black Tie / Posh Frocks</p>
      </div>
      <div id="enter">
        <div class="head">
          <h2 class="enter">Here you can download the entry form for the product categories in The Licensing Awards 2009. These annual product awards are open to all UK and Ireland-based companies and are for officially licensed ranges.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="circle1">1</div>
        <div class="text1">
          <div id="my-border">
            <h5 class="enter">Fill in the form:</h5><br /><span class="enter">Fill in the entry form (one form per entry). <strong>You can download the form <a href="files/entryform.pdf" class="enter">here</a>.</strong></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle2">2</div>
        <div class="text2">
          <div id="my-border1">
            <h5 class="enter">Select your product entries:</h5><br /><span class="enter">Check that the products being entered comply with the entry requirements (i.e. were launched between June 1st 2008 and May 31st 2009). You should submit up to five actual items for each licensed range. Remember &ndash; entries should be license&ndash;specific.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circle3">3</div>
        <div class="text3">
          <div id="my-border2">
            <h5 class="enter">Send your entries:</h5><br /><span class="enter">All entry forms, samples and supporting materials should be sent (arriving no later than June 1st) to:<br /><br /> <span class="enter">The Licensing Awards, Max Publishing, United House, North Road, London, N7 9DP</span>.<br /><br />For further clarification on entering contact Ian Hyder or Jakki Brown at The Licensing Source Book on 202 7700 6740 or by email: <a href="mailto:ianh@max-publishing.co.uk" class="enter">ianh@max-publishing.co.uk</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var browser=navigator.appName;
      var b_version=navigator.appVersion;
      var version=parseFloat(b_version);
      if ((browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") && (version=4)) {  } 
      else {
        var myBorder = RUZEE.ShadedBorder.create({ corner:8, shadow:16 });
        myBorder.render('my-border');
        myBorder.render('my-border1');
        myBorder.render('my-border2');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If someone could shed some light on this or tell me what i'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you remove the JS for the shadeborder, does the problem go away?

Comment: I'm using Opera 9.6 and the site renders properly.

Comment: oh, and if you are using an xhtml doctype, the link tag to your noscript.css should have a closing slash "/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why, as I know sod all about Javascript, but its your shadedbo.js that's causing the error.  Removal of that (and only that) makes the site render correctly on Opera 9.26

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)?  It's the built-in Javascript debugger and also lets you examine the DOM of your page.

There's an [introductory article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-to-opera-dragonfly/) about it on Dev.Opera.

The error console might also help, you can find it under "Tools", "Advanced", "Error Console".  Here's what it shows in my copy of Opera 9.63:

```
CSS - http://clients.bionic-comms.co.uk/licensingawards/microsite/css/style.css
Linked-in stylesheet
Expected ruleset
Line 10:
  # pre, form, fieldset, table, th, td { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
  ---------------------------------------------------------------^
CSS - http://clients.bionic-comms.co.uk/licensingawards/microsite/css/style.css
Linked-in stylesheet
Declaration syntax error
Line 373:
  }
  -^
CSS - http://clients.bionic-comms.co.uk/licensingawards/microsite/enter.html
HTML style attribute
background-position-y is an unknown property
Line 1:
  tion:absolute; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; left:0px; background-position-y:
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to [validate](http://validator.w3.org) this document. You declared it as XHTML, but it isn't. Also you have unescaped reserved characters. (&& in the script part)

I don't think these problems are the reason for your rendering problems, but who nows. Sometimes fixing the warnings resolves the errors :)

Answer (score 0):

The page looks the same to me in Firefox 3.0.6 and Opera 9.62. However, you have a pair of errors in the CSS and a Javascript error that you should look at. Open the error console in Firefox and browse to the page, and you'll see them.